# NetBeans and xdebug - 403 error in new browser tab

Tags: php, apache, debugging, xdebug, netbeans-8

I don't understand why when I press the "Debug Project" button a new browser tab opens with this error:

[image: You don't have permission to access /Impresa2C/index.php on this server.]
Environment:

- Windows and Netbeans 8.1,
- apache v2.4.9, php v5.5.12, xdebug v2.2.5

Details:

- I have already set index.php file located in the root of my project in *Project > Properties > Run Configuration*

Debugging is actually working like a single file debug, but I'd like to fix this in order to get a "clean" environment in which i can work with no worries.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: did you enabled `xdebug` in netbeans?